# get a progress bar in Dash with tqdm

Tags: python-asyncio, plotly-dash, tqdm

I have a the following code that query informations:

```
def get_symbol_price(symbol):
    response = client.fetch_prices(symbol)
    df = pd.DataFrame(response)
    df['symbol'] = symbol
    return df

def get_prices(symbols):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
        results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_symbol_klines, symbols), total=len(symbols)))

    df = pd.concat([result for result in results])
    return df
```

And in my dash app,

```
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Button(id='button'),
        dbc.Progress(id="progress", value=0, striped=True, animated=True),
        dcc.Graph(id='graphs'),
    ],
    fluid=True,
)

@app.callback(
    Output("graphs", "figure"),
    Output("progress", "value"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
)
def update_session(n, interval, data):
    if n is None:
        raise PreventUpdate

    prices = get_prices(symbols)

    fig = go.Figure()

    for symbol, value in prices.groupby('symbol'):
        fig.add_scatter(
            x=value.index,
            y=value,
            name=symbol
        )

    fig.update_yaxes(fixedrange=False, automargin=True)
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)

    return fig
```

But i've a lot of symbols to query that takes up to 1min. How could I display the tqdm progress bar in dash please?